# Regex expression for #include statement

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I am building a node.js json utility which would include external json files and merge after nested lookup. I am struggling with regex which would be able to validate following scenarios

```
!include('other.json') - true
!include("../folder/1.json") - true
!include(./current/external.json) - true
#include('other.json') - false
```

Also the start and end quotations should match:

```
!include('file.json) - false
!include('file.json") - false
```

Regex is not my strength, so any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution with comments:

```js
/^!include\((['"]?)[^'")]+\1\)/
```

- `^` - match the start of a string
- `!include\(` - match the extract string `!include(` (have to escape the parentheses in regex if you want to use it as a literal string)
- `(['"]?)` - create a group (unescaped parentheses) and match either a `'` or `"`. By using `?` we can make the match optional so we can also match nothing
- `[^'")]+` - the `^` means match everything but the `'`, `"`, and `)` characters with the `+` meaning match more than one. That way you won't  match an empty include `!include()`
- `\1` - match whatever was used in group one so we don't have quotation mismatch
- `\)` - match the last closing parentheses

For learning regex I highly recommend Lea Verou's talk [Reg(exp){2}lained/: Demystifying Regular Expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak). You can also create test cases and test regex at https://regexr.com, which also provides a handy cheatsheet.

If you want to play around or expand your test cases, here's a link https://regexr.com/5jepj.